# Cannot get YouCompleteMe to function

Tags: linux-mint, vim, vimrc

I am trying to setup YouCompleteMe (YCM) with vim for my Linux Mint 18.1 KDE machine. I followed the steps on the git page for Ubuntu however cannot get it to work. Is it an issue with Linux Mint or an installation issue?

Also my .vimrc file is empty as there was nothing during the installation that said to edit it.

Is anyone else having this issue?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you followed all steps on [github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) to install YouCompleteMe, so I'm going to skip that part.

Now to get it to work, you'll need a Plugin manager for `vim`, see the [full installation guide](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#full-installation-guide) on the same site.

**Note** I'm going to use [vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) here as plugin manager, but the same works with [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) and [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug), see their respective `README` for details.

To install vundle, get it from github (I recommend using the default directories)

```
$ git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

and put this at the top of your .vimrc (create a file `~/.vimrc` if you don't have one already) to install plugins (example from their site)

```
" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

" YouCompleteMe Plugin
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required

" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line
```

Then, to install the plugins, launch vim and run `:PluginInstall`, or use

```
$ vim +PluginInstall +qall
```

to install plugins from command line.

Check out the instructions in the repo for more details, e.g. on how to update or remove plugins and so on.